# How to use variable table name in CTE

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a CTE defined in my stored procedure, the table name used in the CTE is a variable, for example

```
declare @tblName  char(50)
set @tblName =’…’

;WITH tbl1_CTE AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM @tblName
    …
)
select * from tbl1_CTE
```

However I got an error, Must declare the table variable "@tblName". Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: You'll have to use dynamic sql.  You can't have a table name as a parameter value.

Comment: A CTE is nothing magical. If you restated your question as "how do I use a variable table name in a query", you'd end up with the same answers

Answer (score 3):

The only way to solve this is to use dynamic SQL. For example, the `sp_executesql` procedure. (There are a couple of other SQL Server mechanisms that will do essentially the same thing.

The issue with what you have now is that the value of the variable `@tblName` won't be evaluated until "execute" time.

But before SQL Server can "execute" the statement, SQL Server first has to "prepare" the statement, and as part of that, to figure out whether the referenced table (or view) exists, if the user has privileges on it, what indexes are available, an so on, in order to come up with an execution plan. Once the execution plan for the statement is prepared, then the statement can actually be executed. And it's at this point that the variables will get substituted in.

But, SQL Server needs to know the name of the table *before* it gets to the point where variables are substituted.

The workaround is to use "dynamic SQL". With that approach, the variables, like `@tblName` will get evaluated into the contents of a string. The trick then is to submit that string to SQL Server as a statement. And now, the table name will be a literal within the string.

Comment: I have to use this CTE multiple times in the stored procedure, will it affect the perfomance?

Comment: Well frak yeah, referencing the same CTE in multiple queries will have a performance impact. But that doesn't have anything to do with dynamic SQL. The CTE is going to evaluated in every query it appears in, whether that's static SQL or dynamic SQL. Not having suitable indexes available will affect performance too.

Comment: so instead of using cte, use temp table is better for my case?

Comment: @GLP: there's nothing in the question you asked that indicates that a temporary table would be "better" than a CTE. If the same CTE is referenced in multiple queries, and the CTE is expensive to evaluate, we can sometimes achieve better performance by using a temporary table in place of a CTE. Other times, using a CTE gives better performance. As with a lot of things SQL, the answer is it depends. There's not enough information in your question to make any recommendation as to whether a temporary table would be better than a CTE.

Answer (score 0):

As your error Specified the `@tblname` is a `Variable` but you are using it like a `Temp Table` and selecting from it `Select * from @tblname` we can only use like

```
Select @tblname
```

if it is a Variable